# High-level overview of how can I use my own schema and DAL/ORM (not EF) in conjunction with the default Web API 2 ApplicationOAuthProvider

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, membership, oauth-provider

I am rewriting a web service that is already backed by a relatively large database with existing "membership" tables. The reason I put "membership" in quotes is because the database is an Oracle database and these are not very close to the default aspnet membership tables. I am also using Dapper as my DAL to quickly call existing stored procedures, and of course some of these have to do with authenticating, CRUDding users, etc.

I looked at the default "Individual user accounts" MVC5 Web API 2 project and I have to admit it is a little confusing, but even more so considering that some of the key interfaces and types derive from the `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` namespace, which will probably not work for this project because it is not using Entity Framework. (Please correct me if I am wrong about the last statement.)

So I am a little confused about where to begin and which "Microsoft" classes I will need to implement. I figure that I will need to implement a custom `ExtendedMembershipProvider`, which is already started. Since `IdentityUser` is an EF class I guess I will need to make my own implementation of `IUser` to use in conjunction with the built-in `UserManager<TUser>` and `ApplicationOAuthProvider`.

I have spent some time looking around the web for tutorials on how to implement this form of authentication *without* EF or SQL Server and it's been hard to find even one example.

So if you could shed any light in terms of a high-level overview of how to go about implementing the `ApplicationOAuthProvider` with a custom schema and DAL, I know I would appreciate it and I think there are many others out there as well who are struggling with this because the concepts are fairly abstract and the implementation is so seemingly vendor-specific.

Specifically one thing that would be helpful is a minimal list of classes/interfaces to extend/implement to get going.